# Should I check a CancellationToken before calling EF or allow EF to check it itself?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, cancellation-token

I am adding CancellationTokens into my .NET Core + EF application.

Should I check for cancellation before calling EF, or should I pass the cancellation token to EF and trust that EF will check it itself before starting any work?

"Trust EF to check" approach:

```
...

_context.Users.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

...
```

"Check myself" approach:

```
...

cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
_context.Users.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

...
```

Which approach is recommended?

Comment: No. You don't have to take care of `CancellationToken`

Comment: It's not a matter of 'trusting ef to check'.   All Async functions can be cancelled without any code that physically checks the token.

Comment: @Neil cancellation is cooperative, somewhere the listening code *does* have to check the token to determine if cancellation has been requested and decide what to do about it. See [cancellation in managed threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) as an example.

Comment: @CharlesMager I guess I was thinking more of the base library code for semaphores or reset events would do the heavy lifting.  Sure, if you write a loop yourself, then you will have to check the CTS, but generally, well-written libraries (like EF) will be doing that job for you.